# JSON parsing failing in Arduino and ESP8266

Tags: json, arduino, iot

I have to extract an Ajax response from [this REST API][1]. Please provide a code snippet for this so that  I can proceed I am stuck here.

I need to read JSON data from http://tutor4study.com/forms/ajaxDeviceValue and then I have to parse it.

```
enter code here
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";

const char* host = "tutor4study.com";
const int httpsPort = 80;
 WiFiClient client;
 WiFiClient readClient;
 String sensorValue1 = "5555";
 String sensorValue2 = "9999";
 String readUrl = "";
 char readLine;
 String readResponse ="";
 String readJsonResponse ="";



void setup() {
               Serial.begin(115200);
               Serial.println();
               Serial.print("connecting to ");
               Serial.println(ssid);
               WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
               while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
                                                        delay(500);
                                                        Serial.print(".");
                                                      }
               Serial.println("");
               Serial.println("WiFi connected");
               Serial.println("IP address: ");
               Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
               Serial.print("connecting to ");

                pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
                pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
               // yield();

            }

StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;



void readConnect(){
                   if(!readClient.connect(host,httpsPort)){
                                                            Serial.println("connection failed for readCLient");
                                                            ESP.reset();
                                                            return;
                    }
                   readUrl = "/forms/ajaxDeviceValue";
                    Serial.print("requesting URL: ");
                    Serial.println(readUrl);
                    readClient.print(String("GET ")+readUrl+" HTTP/1.1\r\n"+
                    "Host: "+host+"\r\n"+
                    "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
                    while(readClient.connected()){
                                                  readLine = readClient.read();
                                                  Serial.print(readLine);
                                                  readResponse += readLine;                 
                      }

                      JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(readResponse);

    if (!root.success()) {
    Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
    return;
    }

  }

void loop() {
              readConnect();

            }
```

Aboveis my code. Please have a look at the code and let me know how to read a JSON response for url /ajaxDeviceValue and parse it in a string.

Comment: what did you tried ? do you have some code ?

Comment: [This page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial.WiFi101WeatherAudioNotifier) is a tutorial on json parsing on Arduino using the ArduinoJson Library.

Comment: "Please provide a code snippet for this"  Nope, nope and nope. This is not a "write code for me" website...

Comment: @Johnny Mopp this what I have don't know what do you want .please explain.

Comment: I think this is now better and readable. Please answer now that why my parsing is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a lot of hit and trial I was reading WiFiClient .It was giving me few garbage value with Json response.Because of garbage value ArduinoJson library was not able to parse it. I used HttpClient to read the response andit is returning clear Json which ArduinoJson is able to parse and now code is working fine.